# css class definition with multiple identifiers

Tags: html, css, class

I have just started learning CSS and have come across an example that I do not fully understand. I cannot describe it well which has made finding an answer difficult (I therefore apologise if an answer already exists that I have overlooked).

My question is regarding the following example:

```
.theme-light.slider-wrapper {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

I understand that classes in CSS are defined using the `.name` syntax which can then be used in tags like so:

```
<div class="name"></div>
```

I do not understand how the "double" declaration of `.name1` `.name2` works and how this would be used in a tag.

On a related note the example website that I was given uses an ID in a tag that does not exist in the stylesheet.. where else could this have been defined?

Comment: If you wish to see how it works http://jsfiddle.net/MUc4T/

Comment: the part before the { is called the "selector" Selectors can be defined and combined in lots of different ways. This site may help you understand the possibilities better. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Maybe this use example will clear things up for you.

Imagine the following scenario.

You would have:

```
<div class="general-div">some stuff</div>
<div class="general-div special">some stuff</div>
<div class="general-div">some stuff</div>
<div class="extra-div">some stuff</div>
<div class="extra-div special">some stuff</div>
```

And lets say you want div's to have the same attributes as follows:

```
.general-div {width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid #000;}

.extra-div {width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid #666;}
```

But you want the .general-div with .special class to have red background, and extra-div with .special class to have a blue background.

You would write:

```
.general-div.special {background-color: red;}

.extra-div.special {background-color: blue;}
```

Hope it clears up the use of situation in question.

Comment: thanks, didn't realize I could not have spaces after the periods

Comment: You can have spaces after the periods but then it has a different meaning. If you place a space behind the period it will select the nested item with the given class, and if you have it without the space it will select the element which has all of those classes.

Comment: Good explanation here

Comment: Can I put .general-div on one line and .special on the next line and it will count as if they are connected?

Comment: If you want to do something like <div class="general-div"><div class="special"></div></div> Then you could access the .special div like .general-div .special { <some css definitions>}

Answer (score 89):

In CSS with the `.className` selector you can define the properties for every element with "className" class. Every element could have more classes. 
The meaning of a selector with more classes depends on how you combine them in your declarations:

- `.class1.class2` will match only the elements that have both of them classes defined.

  ```
  .class1.class2 { background: red; }
  <div class="class1 class2"></div>
  ```
- `.class1, .class2` will match the elements with .class1 or .class2

  ```
  .class1, .class2 { background: yellow; }
  <div class="class1"></div>
  <div class="class2"></div>
  ```
- `.class1 .class2` will match only the elements with class2 within elements with class1.

  ```
  .class1 .class2 { background: blue; }
  <div class="class1">
      <div class="class2"></div>
  </div>
  ```

Comment: Well explained. Thanks !

Comment: Very good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`.theme-light.slider-wrapper` just means that it has both classes. In the HTML it could look like this:

```
<div class="theme-light slider-wrapper"></div>
```

As for the ID, there's no reason that an ID in the HTML should have to be referenced in CSS

Answer (score 1):

*How to use double classes, like* `<div class="name1 name2"></div>`?

You `div` has to classes `name1` and `name2` ([see live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U8a45/)).

---

*What about* `.theme-light.slider-wrapper`?

That means your element has to have both  `theme-light` and `slide-wrapper` classes ([see live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BDLCs/)).

It is good for more elements. You want some elements to have gray background. No problem! Add them class `gray` and define css:

```
.gray {
   background: #ddd;
}
```

Also you need some elements have red text. Define `red-text` class with css:

```
.red-text {
   color: red;
}
```

And the end your paragraph has gray background and red text. Just add both `gray` and `red-text` classes like this `<p class="gray red-text">Lorem ipsum</p>`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a detailed explanation for your question.

[image: color-coded class illustration]

From:
www.itsmesharath.in

Answer (score 0):

you have to use

```
<div class="class1 class2">
```

to apply multiple classes to an object.