# while hovering over an object the hidden element does not appear

Tags: css, hover

I am building a roadmap kind of thing on my website, the plan is if you hover over the green dots some speech bubbles should pop up. **.road1** is the class of the first green dot and **.road1k** is the card or speech bubble that should show up. **.road1** reacts to :hover as it is making the dot bigger as intended but somehow .road1k is still not showing up.

Here is my code:

```
.road1 { 

    display: block;
}

.road1k {

display: none;

}

.road1:hover {

      -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
}


.road1:hover .road1k {

    display: block!important;

}
```

And my site
http://rebitsoft.dev.rebitsoft.com/

You might change the language on the top right corner to see the green dots on the mainpage.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS definition is targeting elements with `.road1k` within elements that have the `road1` class. In your html structure, `road1k` is not contained by a `.road1` element. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13444826/8083244 for better details.

Include JQuery Library (head script):

```
<script src="http://rebitsoft.dev.rebitsoft.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0"></script>
```

A simple JQuery solution would be something like (footer script):

```
$('.road1').hover(function() {
    $('.road1k').show();
    }, function(){
    $('.road1k').hide();
});
```

- Leaving as an answer because I don't have the rep to comment on the question.

**Edit** - added outFunction to hover

Comment: You will need to add `http://rebitsoft.dev.rebitsoft.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0` (or another JQuery CDN) back to your `<head>` for this solution to work.

Comment: Last food for thought if you wanted to take a css approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/10483891/8083244

Comment: Hey thanks for your help, I added the two codes to the header.php the jquery code with a <script> tag and the CDN with the <php> tag, nothing really happened, should I paste it in to functions.php?

Comment: @David `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` you need to include the JQuery library still. `<script src="http://rebitsoft.dev.rebitsoft.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0"></script>` within the `<head>`

Comment: https://codepen.io/nopnotme/pen/yLKovwr

Comment: Lovely, it is working, I had to paste it to rebitsoft.js and now its good, bit glitchy but the function is functioning, I think I can handle the rest, cheers to you and thanks again!